# Is there any Built-in Logging Mechanism in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssms

Is there any Built-in Logging Mechanism in SQL Server through which I can Log Information about different Processes in a Stored Procedure.

I Want to Log every step being taken in my Stored Procedure in order to keep record

Comment: Try XEvents, you want `statement_completed` event I think